# Codename One - Picker values on IOS should appear center in landscape mode

Tags: codenameone

I would like to display the picker strings appear at the center of the picker for selection on IOS. Please give me an example if any one already tried it.

[image: IOS Picker]

Answer (score 0):

With every OS update or device change this component breaks because it uses the OS native widgets which are flaky as hell on iOS. We intend to release a completely new API that will render everything in Java and solve these constant regressions, hopefully it will be out for version 5.0 slated for June. We already have a proof of concept but these things take some time always.

You can file an issue on this specific issue but I'm not sure if we'll get a chance to address it. Notice that we need the exact device type and exact OS version as these matter a lot for this specific component.

Comment: Ok Shai. I'm using iphone 6S Plus with Os version:11.2.6 ( 15D100)

Comment: That would help in an issue http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/ as here it would just get lost in the noise (not sure it won't over there too but slightly better chance)